# how to count amount of "heads" and amount of "Tails" produced from random coin flip?

Tags: python, random, counter

i want to count and output the amount of times heads and tails are occur in a coin toss based of a users input of amount of coin tosses they want.

so far with this I get no of heads: 1 and no of tails: 1

i also want to get a count of how many coin flip tries it takes to get a list of all heads and then of all tails, but im struggling with this first!

here is my code:

```
# This program simulates tosses of a coin.
import random
heads = "Heads"
tails = "Tails"
count = 0

def main():
    tosses = int(input("Enter number of tosses:")) 
    coin(tosses)
    print("Total number of heads:",(heads.count(heads)))
    print("Total number of tails:", (tails.count(tails)))
    
#end of main function    

def coin(tosses):
    for toss in range(tosses):
        # Simulate the coin toss.
        if random.randint(1, 2) == 1:
            print(heads)
        else:
            print(tails)
    return (heads.count(heads),(tails.count(tails)))
        # end of if statement
     #end of for loop   
#end of coin function

            
# Call the main function.
main()
```

Comment: You want to actually keep counters for either, and in the place where you now use `print(heads)` and `print(tails)`, add to the appropriate counter.

Comment: Put differently, think about how you would do this _on paper_. Then replace paper with variables and you are already most of the way there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some edits to your code! It doesn't need to be as complicated as you made it to be. Let me know if you have any questions!

```
# This program simulates tosses of a coin.
import random

# function to toss coins and increment head/tail counts
def coin(tosses):

    # store the counts of each respective result
    heads = 0
    tails = 0

    for toss in range(tosses):
        # simulate the coin toss
        if random.randint(1, 2) == 1:
            print("Heads!")
            heads+=1 # increment count for heads
        else:
            print("Tails!")
            tails+=1 # increment count for tails

    return heads, tails

# main function
def main():
    # get user input
    tosses = int(input("Enter number of tosses:")) 

    # toss coins
    heads, tails = coin(tosses)

    # print final result
    print("Total number of heads:", heads)
    print("Total number of tails:", tails)


# call the main function
main()
```

Comment: thank you so much worked pefectly!! i understand now :)

Answer (score 0):

These edits fix your problem and align with the previous comments.

```
import random
heads = "Heads"
tails = "Tails"
heads_count = 0
tails_count = 0

def main():
    tosses = int(input("Enter number of tosses:"))
    coins = coin(tosses)
    print("Total number of heads:",coins[0])
    print("Total number of tails:", coins[1])

def coin(tosses):
    global heads_count
    global tails_count
    for toss in range(tosses):
        # Simulate the coin toss.
        if random.randint(1, 2) == 1:
            print(heads)
            heads_count+=1
        else:
            print(tails)
            tails_count+=1
    return (heads_count,tails_count)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution that use the `collections` module to return the amount of heads and tails tossed:

```
from random import choice
from collections import Counter

count = int(input("Enter number of tosses: "))
results = Counter([choice(['heads','tails']) for _ in range(count)])
heads, tails = results['heads'], results['tails']

print("total number of heads:", heads)
print("total number of tails:", tails)
```